# Getting stuck in mobile UI automation Appium using robot framework python

Tags: python, robotframework, appium-android

I was trying to automate a mobile app using **robot framework python** and got stuck in **click element keyword**. The script is failing with the error mentioned below.

My code:

```
Click Element   //android.widget.Button[contains(text(),'JOIN')]
```

Error:

```
Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Click Element' expected 2 arguments, got 1.
```

After getting this error, I changed my code as below

My code:

```
Click Element   //android.widget.Button[contains(text(),'JOIN')]    None
```

Error:

```
TypeError: click_element() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

So, I am a little bit confused what to enter as argument

I referred the appiumLibrary keyword documentation of Robot framework. One argument is mentioned there and that is locator. 
Below is the link of the library-

http://%20http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html

Not only `click element keyword`, in every keyword it is always asking for one more argument than is present in the documentation. Some keywords are working with an extra `None` (i.e, click text) but most of the keywords like click button, input text is not working.

Below is the whole code i was using and without this click element the code is working fine and the app is opening.

```
Open Application    ${appium_host}  ${alias}    platformName=${platformName}   platformVersion=${platformVersion}    deviceName=${deviceName}    appPackage=${appPackage}   appActivity=${appactivity}  appWaitActivity=${appactivity},${appwaitactivity}
sleep   6
Click Element   //android.widget.Button[contains(text(),'JOIN')]    None
```

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Ankita

Comment: Could you properly format your code the way you are actually using it? It might potentially help in finding out what's wrong. Remember that in RF, you need to separate arguments by at least 2 spaces, so if you by any chance don't use it like this, you might see similar errors.

Comment: @pavelsaman Yeah I am using tab between keyword and arguments which was written in RF documentation.

Comment: @pavelsaman I have have edited the original post and aded the whole code there.

Comment: Are you really using `AppiumLibrary.Click Element` keyword? Don't you import some other library that contains the same keyword but with different arguments?

Comment: Yeah I am using AppiumLibrary only. You can see the 1st error in my original post written- "Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Click Element' expected 2 arguments, got 1."

Comment: True that. I don't see anything wrong there. Perhaps someone else knows. I'd normally try to change and check what I can: e.g. versions of libraries, locators etc. Something might give you an additional piece of information that you need to solve this.